# How to set the starting position of a ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have been trying to set the initial position of a `ScrollView` but have not found a way. Does anyone have any ideas? Also, I have a GoogleMaps fragment as children of the `ScrollView`.

Comment: Have you tried scrollview.setScrollY(<some_int>) during onResume?

Comment: hey buddy thanks for the quick response but I just tried it on resume :  scrollView = (ScrollViewExtend)findViewById(R.id.merchantScroll);
   scrollView.setScrollY(400);     ... no luck : ( the only way that has worked for me was "onWindowFocusChanged"  but this is only when the view is shown to the user so you can see the scroll to that certain position.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, that is possible:

```
ScrollView.scrollTo(int x, int y);
ScrollView.smoothScrollTo(int x, int y);
ScrollView.smoothScrollBy(int x, int y);
```

can be used for that. The x and y parameters are the coordinates to scroll to on the horizontal and vertical axis.

Example in code:

```
    @Override   
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        sv.scrollTo(0, 100);
     }
```

In that example, once the `Activity` is started, your `ScrollView` will be scrolled down 100 pixels.

You can also try to **delay** the scrolling process:

```
final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

Handler h = new Handler();

h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        sv.scrollTo(0, 100);            
    }
}, 250); // 250 ms delay
```

Comment: hey Philip I just tried it and it does not work for me   : ScrollView scrollView32 = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.merchantScroll);
   scrollView32.scrollTo(0,300);

Comment: Can you think of another reason why it may not be working? I have a button on screen that when clicked it will move the scrollView to the correct position(works) but I cannot set the initial position(doesn't work)

Comment: Are you adding other views to your scrollview at runtime? You could also try to delay the scolling, I will show you in an example above.

Comment: hey philip i actually implemented that before looking at your answer and it works : D but that is the accepted asnwer.

Comment: Maybe it was because you move before add the content or information to listview

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is not working for me. There is no direct way to set the initial position of a scroll view.

However, you can set the initial position before drawing the scroll view, like this:

```
rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        scrollView.setScrollY(100);
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can also use `scrollView.setScrollY(100)` inside `Handler`, but that will be jerky while scrolling.

Comment: This answer works almost fine in most situation, except launching app when screen is locked. Using ```onWindowFocusChanged``` is more stable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507976/android-setting-position-of-hortizontal-scrollview

Answer (score 2):

```
Scrollview sw = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
sw.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
           sw.smoothScrollTo(0, 5000);
     }
});
```

Comment: I your really think that this is THE solution, be proud and make a good edit with at least explanations. And please read stackoverflow documentation because this is not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers worked for me. My `ScrollView` is part of a surrounding `LinearLayout`. I put the adjustment of the `ScrollView` into the `onDraw()` method of this `LinearLayout` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    if(scrollAdjustTries > 2){
        return;
    }
    scrollAdjustTries++;
    mScrollView.scrollTo(0, mModel.scrollLine());
}
```

Very ugly, but working.

Answer (score 2):

After several hours internet searching

this worked for me :

```
ScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
//setting position here :
        ScrollView.scrollTo(X, Y);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ScrollView doesn't know its size before it been laid out. A solution is to save the scroll position unil *onLayout* has been called and then set the scroll position.

Here is an example (kotlin):

```
class MyScrollView constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : ScrollView(context, attrs) {

    private var hasStartPositionBeenSet = false
    var startPosition = 0

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)

        if(!hasStartPositionBeenSet) {
             scrollTo(0, startPosition)
             hasStartPositionBeenSet = true
        }
    }
}

class MyActivity: Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        /* ... */
        findViewById<MyScrollView>(R.id.scrollView).startPosition = scrollPosition
    }
}
```