# Layout issue with Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I am using appcompat-v7 v21 and I have a problem with toolbar and rest of the layout in the activity.

The view looks fine in the portrait mode, but when turned to landscape, the views are going behind the Toolbar. Please refer to screenshots.

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

toolbar_without_spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_without_spinner" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_imageview_profile_photo"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_thumbnail" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/profile_edittext_firstname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="@string/signup_first_name"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords" >
                    </EditText>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/profile_edittext_lastname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="@string/signup_last_name"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_textview_display_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/display_name_hint"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_textview_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/email_hint"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/profile_edittext_about"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="top|left"
                    android:hint="@string/profile_about"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:lines="5"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:minLines="3"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/profile_edittext_twitter_handle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/profile_twitter_hanle"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/profile_edittext_website"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/profile_website"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/profile_button_edit_cancel"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.50"
                        android:text="@string/profile_cancel" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/profile_button_edit_profile"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.50"
                        android:text="@string/profile_edit" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, in portrait mode, if i try to enter text in any of the edittext, the views are going behind the toolbar.

Comment: check this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307239/how-to-set-the-starting-position-of-a-scrollview

Comment: @MSGadag, I want to do it with XML. Any ideas?

Comment: `layout="@layout/toolbar_without_spinner"` is not the same layout as `toolbar.xml`?

Comment: its the same.. will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the LinearLayout inside the scrollview. Change the LinearLayout's layout_gravity as follows:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
       </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```