# How to bring an image in the center of horizontal scroll view?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, galleryview

I have a horizontal scroll view placed below a map The map has some markers and the horizontal scroll view contains images for each of the markers.

Now, when ever user clicks a maker,I want the horizontal view to scroll and image for that marker to come to the center. This could have been a bit easier with the gallery view, but since that has been deprecated, how shall I go about it now?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:gravity="center"
```

post that in the xml

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you want to manually scroll your ScrollView to a specific position.

You should use the scrollTo() method to perform that.
Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507976/android-setting-position-of-hortizontal-scrollview) which has an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:gravity="center"` in your `layout.xml` file to center all the images in the `scrollView`.

Use `yourScrollView.scrollTo(x,y)` to automatically select the relevant image.