# Android - Scroll to Selected Child Position in ChipGroup

Tags: android, android-chips

I am trying to make An Activity with 4 `Chips` in a Horizontal Scrolling `ChipGroup`.

This Activity is using the `ChipGroup` as a filter for API call, and can have Extras telling which Chip was selected by user.

Currently I'm doing it like :

```
chipScroll.postDelayed(() -> {
                chipScroll.smoothScrollBy(800, 0);
            },100);
```

But this is quite a hacky solution to what I want to achieve.

Is there any other way to scroll to selected `Chip` in a Horizontal Scrolling `ChipGroup`?

Edit :

I've thought of trying to iteratively get all the Chips in the `ChipGroup` and match its IDs. But it seems hacky too. Something like `spinnerAdapter.getItem(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition)` is what I'm aiming for

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507976/android-setting-position-of-hortizontal-scrollview).

I forgot that `ChipGroup` is basically just a `ViewGroup`, and `HorizontalScrollView` is just an extra for its scrolling purpose.

I could just do something like :

```
chipGroup.post(() -> {
    Chip chipByTag = chipGroup.findViewWithTag(filterModel.getComplaint_status());
    chipGroup.check(chipByTag.getId());
    chipScroll.smoothScrollTo(chipByTag.getLeft() - chipByTag.getPaddingLeft(), chipByTag.getTop());
});
```

Doing this in `onCreate` would crash as the `Tag` isn't assigned yet, and I'm using `DataBinding` for the tag in XML (CMIIW), hence, we should do it in a `.post()` runnable.

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin: Using @Kevin Murvie answer

```
binding.layoutChipChoiceProducts.chipGroupDrinksChoice.post {
        val chip =
            binding.layoutChipChoiceProducts.chipGroupDrinksChoice.findViewWithTag<Chip>(tag)
        binding.layoutChipChoiceProducts.scrollLayoutChip.scrollTo(
            chip.left - chip.paddingLeft, chip.top
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your ChipGroup with the HorizontalScrollView, and just call this extension function after the chip selection:

```
inline fun <reified T : View> HorizontalScrollView.scrollToPosition(
    tag: String?,
) {
    val view = findViewWithTag<T>(tag) ?: return
    val leftEdgePx = view.left
    val screenCenterPx = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2
    val scrollPx = if (leftEdgePx < screenCenterPx) 0
    else leftEdgePx - screenCenterPx + view.width / 2
    this.post {
        this.smoothScrollTo(scrollPx, view.top)
    }
}
```

This will always show selected chip centered on the screen (if it's possible).